# Dynamic Vertex Buffer to Move Sprites Around DirectX

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to move a sprite around on the screen with 2D rendering in DirectX

I'm reading on a tutorial that utilizes a dynamic vertex buffer to move these sprites around.. however, I'm wondering...

What's wrong with using a translation matrix to move these around? It is my understanding that dynamic vertex buffers are inefficient in most cases.

Comment: That depends on how the rendering is done. Does the vertex buffer contain the actual vertices or are they generated in a geometry shader? Generally, sending one position (3 x 4 byte) to the graphics card is faster than sending a whole matrix (4 x 4 x 4 byte). But that depends on the buffer configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, this can be done with a translation matrix. Without seeing the tutorial you're talking about, it's difficult to guess their rationale for using a dynamic vertex buffer, it could be purely pedagogic.